# Search query returns empty results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am not receiving any returned results when I do a search query.

```
  def index
        @users = User.where(zip_code: locations.map(&:zipcode))
        @users = User.search(params[:search].gsub(/\s+/, ' | '))
```

Though if I do what's below it returns the results:

```
@users = User.where(zip_code: locations.map(&:zipcode))
else
@users = User.search(params[:search].gsub(/\s+/, ' | '))
```

Why is it that I have to add **else**? Shouldn't I be able to run both? I want to run both of them at the same time to get the expected return results.

In other parts of my  app I can have it look like the original code above and it works as expected. But in this controller it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would need to see more of your code but i guess it is related to your `#search` method being a method. :p

To chain methods like:

```
User.where(zip_code: locations.map(&:zipcode)).search(params[:search].gsub(/\s+/, ' | '))
```

you will need the search method to be an scope. =)